# Exim4, can't send email on my own domain that is in another server

Tags: email-server, exim, email-bounces

I use exim4 as a send only email on my servers,
The FQDM I have on this servers is ws1.example.com  (ws1,ws2,ws3...) and the email I use for receiving emails is a different smtp server with the email address being info@example.com , when I send email from my ws[num].example.com servers to any other service like gmail and hotmail everything works fine, also when I send email from any service(gmail,hostname..) to info@example.com everything works fine too, the problem is when I send emails from the ws[num].example.com servers to info@example.com I get "info@example.com: Unrouteable address" . Maybe the servers lookup for the address in the local hosts file since it is the same domain? How do I love it?

Comment: Are you NATing private addresses to public? Is the problem that it's trying to route from private --> public --> private and the NAT rules aren't set up to understand this?

Comment: It looks like problem is indeed that @example.com is treated as a local domain that your ws1.example.com host itself is responsible for. You might want to check the `domainlist local_domains` settings in your config.

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring your server to use the `smarthost` option.  Use  your mail server as the smarthost.  If the name resolves to an Internet address, you may need to connect by IP address, add a host entry or configure hairpin NAT to your mail server.